# react-native-agora - callApi RtcEngine_initialize {"context":{"appId":"xxx"}} Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods

Tags: react-native, agora.io, agora-implementation

i got task to implement voice calling using react-native-agora, i have try the documentation instruction
https://docs.agora.io/en/voice-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=react-native

and this example https://github.com/AgoraIO-Extensions/react-native-agora/blob/main/example/src/examples/basic/JoinChannelAudio/JoinChannelAudio.tsx

but still, i get an error like this

callApi RtcEngine_initialize {"context":{"appId":"xxx"}} Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods

`"react-native-agora": "^4.2.1", "react-native": "0.68.0",`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).